# Why do I get the wrong date?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I currently have this method:

```
function fill_date_jaarlijks()
{
    var today = new Date();
$("#datepicker_eind").datepicker("setDate", new Date(today.getFullYear()+1,today.getMonth(),today.getDay()));
}
```

What it should do is, return the date of (today + 1 year).

What it actually returns is 01 December 2012, while today's date is 19 December 2011.

Could someone explain?

Comment: just to be sure, can you previously check your system date? (just to be sure we're dealing with the right current date)

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the functions you're using when you realised that they're not doing what you expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getDay` returns **day of week**

Use `getDate` instead.

Or better still:

```
var dateValue = new Date();
dateValue.setFullYear(dateValue.getFullYear() + 1);
$("#datepicker_eind").datepicker("setDate", dateValue);
```